# I am trying to draw circles and add popup on a map, but i keep getting errors. Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'lng')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-component, react-leaflet

1. This piece of code is from my App.js
2. I am using this as the default location of the map once the app opens

   `const [mapCenter, setMapCenter] = useState({lat: 34.80746, lng: -40.4796});`
3. I use this to update the location of the map, as selected from the dropdown menu, I am getting the lat and lng from data pulled from an endpoint

   `setMapCenter([data.countryInfo.lat, data.countryInfo.lng]);`
4. I am passing the following props to the Map

   ````
    ```<Map center={mapCenter}
      zoom={mapZoom}
      countries={mapCountries}
      casesType={casesType}
      />```
   ````
5. This is from my utils.js file, colors of the said circles according to their case types

   ````
    ```import { Circle, Popup } from "react-leaflet";

      const casesTypeColors = {
      cases: {
        hex: "#CC1034",
        rgb: "rgb(204, 16, 52)",
       half_op: "rgba(204, 16, 52, 0.5)",
       multiplier: 800,
        },

      recovered: {
       hex: "#7dd71d",
       rgb: "rgb(125, 215, 29)",
       half_op: "rgba(125, 215, 29, 0.5)",
        multiplier: 1200,
      },
        deaths: {
       hex: "#fb4443",
       rgb: "rgb(251, 68, 67)",
        half_op: "rgba(251, 68, 67, 0.5)",
       multiplier: 2000,
       },
       };```
   ````
6. This is from my utilis.js. I am trying to draw the circle and popup on the map. Console error (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'lng')

   ````
     ```export const showDataOnMap = (data, casesType = "cases") => (
       data.map((country) => ( 
       <Circle >
       center = {[country.countryInfo.lat, country.countryInfo.long]} 

         fillOpacity = {0.4},
        color={casesTypeColors[casesType].hex},
        fillColor={casesTypeColors[casesType].hex}, 

       radius={
        Math.sqrt(country[casesType]) * casesTypeColors[casesType].multiplier
      } 
       <Popup>
        <h6>Is the POPUP working</h6>
     </Popup>
     </Circle>
       ))
       );```
   ````
7. This is from my Map.js. Console error (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'lng')

   ````
         ```import { showDataOnMap } from './utils';

           function Map({center, zoom, countries, casesType}) {
                return (
              <div className='map'>
      <LeafletMap center={center} zoom={zoom} scrollWheelZoom={false} >
         <TileLayer
         attribution='&copy; <a 
         href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
            url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
           />
            {showDataOnMap(countries, casesType)} 
      </LeafletMap>
                 </div>
            )
             }

             export default Map```
   ````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your `showDataOnMap` function where you render the `Circle`:

```
<Circle >
    center = {[country.countryInfo.lat, country.countryInfo.long]} 
    fillOpacity = {0.4},
    color={casesTypeColors[casesType].hex},
    fillColor={casesTypeColors[casesType].hex}, 
    radius={
     Math.sqrt(country[casesType]) * casesTypeColors[casesType].multiplier
    } 
  <Popup>
    <h6>Is the POPUP working</h6>
  </Popup>
</Circle>
```

All of the properties of the Circle (`center`, `fillOpacity`, `color` etc) are defined after you've already closed the Circle element with a `>`. This should be changed to:

```
<Circle
      center={[country.countryInfo.lat, country.countryInfo.long]}
      fillOpacity={0.4}
      color={casesTypeColors[casesType].hex}
      fillColor={casesTypeColors[casesType].hex}
      radius={
        Math.sqrt(country[casesType]) * casesTypeColors[casesType].multiplier
      }
    >
```

There's a working demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-leaflet-example-zf7op8?file=Map.tsx) that renders the circles.